# 2015 Toyota RAV4 XLE creaking noise

Tags: toyota, vibration

My car has 35k miles and was recently in a front end collision when an elderly lady ran a red light. My car was in an autobody shop for one month, and when I got it back, it made a sound like a door creaking, every time I came to a complete stop. It sounds like it’s coming from the front passenger area. I took it back there 3 more times-they thought it was the heat shield, and when they “bent” it, it would help for about 5 minutes, then it would do it again. I also took it to the dealership, and they thought it was from the frame.

Now, 3 months after the collision, the sound only occurs when the engine is cold. It makes the sound even when I’m just shifting from drive to reverse with my foot still on the brake pedal. Another seemingly related symptom is that when the sound is occurring, my car vibrates more when I’m idling-however when the creaking noise is no longer evident when the engine is warm, the vibration is better as well. This makes me think it’s either the motor or transmission mount. I’m kinda pointing more towards a motor mount with the vibration at a complete stop. What do you guys think?